# How to animate 2 objects with 2 different animations one after another in 3 js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on creating an animation in 3 js. I am beginner at it and I figured out how to animate for 1 object by using the VectorKeyframeTrack function. I would like to perform it for 2 different animation (not group) for 2 different objects one after the other.  I have gotten it to work concurrently, i.e. play the animation at the same time. How do I get the rectangle to move once the sphere has looped through 4 times. I was planning to use setTimeout. Is there a better way?

```
const animationClip = new THREE.AnimationClip(null,3, [track1]);
const animationClip1 = new THREE.AnimationClip(null,3, [track]);
const animationAction = mesh.userData.mixer.clipAction(animationClip);
const animationAction1 = cube.userData.mixer.clipAction(animationClip1);

animationAction.setLoop(THREE.LoopRepeat ,4);
animationAction.play();
setTimeout(function(){
   animationAction1.setLoop(THREE.LoopRepeat ,4);
   animationAction1.play(); 
},6000);
```

Here is the js fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/bpyLsfda/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a better way?

Yes. Instead of using `setTimeout()`, you can register an event listener to the first animation mixer and listen for the `finished` event. Your code does now look like this:

```
mesh.userData.mixer.addEventListener( 'finished', ( /*event*/ ) => {

    animationAction1.setLoop( THREE.LoopRepeat ,4 );
    animationAction1.play(); 

} );
```

The event is fired when the playback of an animation action has been completed. You can also extract the respective action from the `event` object via `event.action`.

https://jsfiddle.net/6hzr0a9v/

`three.js R106`